# Refine a string to only certain values scala

Tags: scala, refinement-type

Is there any way to refine a string to only a certain subset of values? For example, I have a list of 500 keys in a hash map. But I only want certain keys to be inserted. For example, "abcd" and "aaaa" are valid keys but "abdc" is invalid. Is there any way to refine the String to only one of the given 500 keys?

I'm guessing the way to do this is just a very long regexp that matches `abcd|aaaa`?

*Edit*: Using the **fthomas/refined** library specifically the `MatchesRegex` function. Want to know if there is a better approach that I'm missing out on.

Comment: Take a look to **fthomas/refined**, particular to their [`MatchesRegex[S]` _predicate_](https://github.com/fthomas/refined#provided-predicates).

Comment: Should have been more specific. Yes. *fthomas/refined* is what I'm looking at. Just wanted to see if there was a better way to do it other than just using a very long regexp. I know that the list of fields is finite. So I'm going to just generate a list of all 500 fields that are known. Wanted to know if there was a better way to do it than `MatchesRegex`.

Comment: If you can not find a good regex for all your keys, maybe a combination of `AnyOf` and `Equals`, and instead of write all the refined types yourself. Write and **SBT** generator task that creates them from a list, file, db or whatever that can help you reduce the boilerplate, at then you will have a type alias `ValidKey` that you could import and use in your main code. _(Disclaimer, I have not used refined, not sure if that would be compiler bomb)_.

Comment: Yes. I was going to write out a generator task to create the refined boilerplate. Not sure what you mean by combination of `AnyOf` and `Equals` though.

Comment: The `Equals[T]` _predicate_ ensures the value is equals to the other _(example: `String Refined Equal[W.`"abcd"`.T]`)_. And the `anyOf[PS]` ensures the type is valid for at least one of the given `HList` of _predicates_. Again, i have not used it yet, so is just and idea. - That is why I just leave the comments instead of a proper answer :)

Comment: Very much appreciated either way. I will look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scala 3 seems to [Allow Singletons in Unions #6299](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/pull/6299) like so

```
val refinedString: "abcd" | "aaaa" = "aaaa"
```

whilst `abdc` would result in the following error

```
val refinedString: "abcd" | "aaaa" = "abdc"
                                     ^^^^^^
                           Found:    String("abdc")
                           Required: String("abcd") | String("aaaa")
```

It worked for me with Dotty Scala version `0.15.0-bin-20190517-fb6667b-NIGHTLY`.

Comment: Would prefer not to use non-production ready versions of Scala. Also needs to refine about 500 different hash keys. Not sure of the performance of this in Dotty? (Or in fthomas/refined for that matter.)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up actually just using generated source code that has every known key inside a `MatchesRegex` `(a|b..)` construct for 500 keys. It works. It's not pretty but it's also generated source code that I don't have to deal with so it's okay, I guess.